# When trying to find the optimal volume of water for a bottle rocket, do I use constant or increasing pressure?

Tags: pressure, rocket-science

I am conducting an experiment to find the optimum amount of water for a given rocket. For each trial, do I keep the pressure same or do I increase pressure with increasing volumes.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to study or show.

Answer (score 0):

For maximum acceleration and altitude you will want the air pressure as high as possible in each test. With increasing amounts of water you will have lesser air space. When more of the water is expelled in flight, the air pressure will drop as the available air space increases. acceleration increases the most as the last of the water is pushed out, because without all that water the rocket weighs less. So having the most air pressure possible as the last of the water is pushed out would be optimal. Having the same pressure each test, if it is less than maximum, could result in lower performances with greater amounts of water, as the pressure could become to low at the last of the water is pushed out.